# Meaning behind the conjugacy class in describing geometry of solids

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

When we consider the group of rotataional symmetry , say of a cube or a dodecahedron, it is not difficult to see the symmetry group is isomorphic to a $S_4$ , $A_5$ respectively. Mooreover, when you look over the conjugacy class of $S_4, A_5$, the conjugacy class indeed have some geometric meaning, say the conjugacy class of a 4 cycle  and 2,2 cycle is in $S_4$ is the rotation along the axis passing through one face to another and the class of transposition is the rotation along the axis of edges to edges.

Then i found some wired phenomenon about the class which i cannot explain. The rotation along the axis of a face always consist of 2 classes , say the rotation of a face in a cube gives 2 class, the class of 4 cycle (....) and a classes of 2,2 cycle (..)(..) while all other rotation axis symmetry of a cube will only give one classes. This properties is valid for all platonic solid and the polygonal plane, like the square or a triangle.

My question: What is the geometric meaning behind the conjugacy class, why only the class of rotation of a face will consist of 2 different classes while all others rotational symmetry will only have 1 single class?

Comment: Does your question include a rotation axis passing through two vertices?